# Case When Syntax Is Returning Extra NULLS

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a Case When in the below code and the outcome produces extra NULL values that should not be there. Any ideas what I am doing wrong with the below code?

```
SELECT distinct
Case when
status_level = 'CLAIM'
AND 
 status = 'CLOSED'
THEN effective_date
END FirstCloseDate
FROM 
STATUS
```

Current results are:

```
+----------------+
| FirstCloseDate |  
+----------------+
| (null)         |  
| 02-JUL-18      |  
+----------------+
```

Result should be

```
+----------------+
| FirstCloseDate |  
+----------------+
| 02-JUL-18      |  
+----------------+
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` yields `NULL` if none of the `WHEN` branches match and no `ELSE` branch is defined. So you get `NULL`s for records where `status_level = 'CLAIM' AND status = 'CLOSED'` is not satisfied.

Your expected result looks like you just want records, that fulfill the `status_level = 'CLAIM' AND status = 'CLOSED'` condition. To filter records use a `WHERE` clause not a `CASE` in the list of columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       effective_date firstclosedate
       FROM status
       WHERE status_level = 'CLAIM'
             AND status = 'CLOSED';
```

You can additionally filter `effective_date`s that are `NULL` should there be any if you want to omit them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       effective_date firstclosedate
       FROM status
       WHERE status_level = 'CLAIM'
             AND status = 'CLOSED'
             AND effective_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, the where clause fixed the problem I was experiencing. Thank you very much!